# How can I see all commercial destinations to a country from a particular airport?

Tags: flight-schedules

I live in Las Vegas, which obviously has a large airport with a broad array of international flights. Is there a quick way for me to see all the non-stop commercial flights that are available to Mexico? I don't need to necessarily know the airline, just which cities are available for non-stops from Las Vegas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs more to [Travel.SE]

Comment: @anshabhi if any of that were true then answers wouldn't have been generated. The idiot mods on here prefer to close over dumb rules instead of letting the communities thrive. Don't be a moron and sacrifice results for process

Comment: @JimBeam Just because the users here have good answers doesn't mean that it is on topic, or that your question would not also have good answers on another site.

Comment: @anshabhi you people are ridiculous

Comment: Even I agree with that. The moderation here is really very strict and now they are over to hunt the comments as well. This is an older post and in newer ones, the mods are recklessly deleting even a little off-topic comments. It appears that they want to apply some very harsh standards of quality here, as if they were manufacturing some aircraft... I voted your question as off-topic, because it just appeared to be.. but seriously, we people are "ridiculous".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a number of websites which can provide this information. Wikipedia and the specific airline's website can be a great resource too.

- [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/) gives you a graphical representation of direct flights from a particular airport. It appears that this service is for all major airports across the globe.
- [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.net/airports/airports-of-the-world.html) can provide the information you are looking for. As for your example, you'll enter Las Vegas in the `From` text area, and then leave the `To` area blank. It will search **all** destinations (grouped by countries) where there are direct flights (or with one stop) available.

Comment: Thank you. Open flights is basically exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia entries for airports almost always have the list of destinations served from the airport, and I think the plane-spotter community keeps them very up to date. But it is indexed by airline, not country. Given the likelihood of there being only 2-3 destination airports in a single country, you could search on those city names - or else just browse the list.

The entry for McCarran International in Las Vegas is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarran_International_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations

Answer (score 3):

For seeing all non-stop flights, you may use any travel website. See this example using [Cleartrip](http://www.cleartrip.com/flights/international/results?from=LAX&to=MEX&depart_date=19/06/2015&adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&intl=y&sd=1434607961827&stops=0&tripDuration=2-23&layoverDuration=0-16) for non-stop flights between LA and Mexico.

And, you can use any flight tracker for all the cities served by an airport. Have the knowledge of airlines and airliner as well! [Here](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/airport/KLAX/departures/all) are all the departures from KLAX by [Flightaware](http://www.flightaware.com). Alternately, you may check for the airport's website to see all the destinations served by an airport (available at websites of only few airports). For ex. [here](http://www.edinburghairport.com/flights/destinations-and-airlines) are all the destinations served by Edinburgh airport.

And, if these don't work out, go with timbo's idea!